# Running Moxy 2.7.1 in Websphere Liberty 18.0.0.1

Tags: websphere-liberty, moxy

I'm trying to use the moxy mashaller in a small REST service. Here is the code snipped:

```
  @GET
  @Path("ping")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public String transform() {
    StringWriter result = new StringWriter();
    try {
     JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Partner.class);
     Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
     marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

     marshaller.marshal(new Partner(), result);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     throw new RuntimeException(e);
   }
  return result.toString();
 }
```

The service is deployed in a websphere liberty 18.0.0.1 with the following server.xml:

```
<server description="Moxy">
<featureManager>
  <feature>javaee-7.0</feature>
  <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>
<applicationManager autoExpand="true" />
<applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean" />
```

The dependencies im my pom:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

When I call the service, I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Unable to create context
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:116)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:65)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:56)
    at de.signaliduna.moxy.PartnerResource.ping(PartnerResource.java:27)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:114)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/eclipse/persistence/jaxb/compiler/Generator.generateSchemaFiles(Ljavax/xml/bind/SchemaOutputResolver;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/util/Map; @90: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/schema/SchemaModelProject' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/eclipse/persistence/core/sessions/CoreProject'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @90
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/eclipse/persistence/jaxb/compiler/Generator', 'javax/xml/bind/SchemaOutputResolver', 'java/util/Map', 'org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/schema/SchemaModelProject', 'org/eclipse/persistence/oxm/XMLContext', 'org/eclipse/persistence/oxm/XMLMarshaller' }
    stack: { 'org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/schema/SchemaModelProject', 'java/lang/Class' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2a2c 2ab4 002c b700 c22a b400 312a b400
    0x0000010: 2cb6 0093 2ab4 002c b600 972a b400 2cb6
    0x0000020: 009a 2ab4 002c b600 9d2a b400 2cb6 00a0
    0x0000030: 2ab4 002c b600 8d2b b601 3abb 00c6 59b7
    0x0000040: 00c8 4ebb 00c9 592d c000 cbb7 00cd 3a04
    0x0000050: 1904 b600 d03a 052d 12d4 b600 d6c0 00dc
    0x0000060: 3a06 2ab4 0031 b600 ba3a 0719 07b9 00de
    0x0000070: 0100 3a09 a700 5f19 09b9 00e4 0100 c000
    0x0000080: d43a 0819 08b6 0102 3a0a 190a 1301 0613
    0x0000090: 0108 b601 0a19 0619 0ab9 0110 0200 1908
    0x00000a0: b601 3d99 000d 1908 b601 403a 0ba7 0013
    0x00000b0: 2b19 08b6 0144 1908 b600 fab6 0147 3a0b
    0x00000c0: 1905 1908 190b b601 4da7 000a 3a0a 190a
    0x00000d0: b601 5019 09b9 011f 0100 9aff 9d2a b400
    0x00000e0: 31b6 0122 b0                           
  Exception Handler Table:
    bci [131, 201] => handler: 204
  Stackmap Table:
    full_frame(@119,{Object[#1],Object[#328],Object[#81],Object[#215],Object[#201],Object[#282],Object[#220],Object[#223],Top,Object[#229]},{})
    full_frame(@176,{Object[#1],Object[#328],Object[#81],Object[#215],Object[#201],Object[#282],Object[#220],Object[#223],Object[#212],Object[#229],Object[#267]},{})
    append_frame(@192,Object[#347])
    full_frame(@204,{Object[#1],Object[#328],Object[#81],Object[#215],Object[#201],Object[#282],Object[#220],Object[#223],Object[#212],Object[#229]},{Object[#337]})
    full_frame(@211,{Object[#1],Object[#328],Object[#81],Object[#215],Object[#201],Object[#282],Object[#220],Object[#223],Top,Object[#229]},{})
```

Do I have to active a feature in the WLP or am I missing an dependency in my pom?

If anyone need further information, I support it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In the Open-Liberty discussion group someone tries to change the cache of eclipse link in WLP (see https://groups.io/g/openliberty/topic/20719688#165). 
One hint was to remove the jpa feature and use the jpa container feature.

I was using the complete jee7 feature, which includes the jpa feature.

While there is (still) no exclusion tag for the jpa feature all the jee features have to be listed excluding the jpa feature and including the jpa-container feature.

My solution:

```
  <featureManager>
    <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
    <feature>beanValidation-1.1</feature>
    <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jca-1.7</feature>
    <feature>jms-2.0</feature>
    <feature>ejbPersistentTimer-3.2</feature>
    <feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature>
    <feature>j2eeManagement-1.1</feature>
    <feature>jdbc-4.1</feature>
    <feature>wasJmsServer-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jaxrs-2.0</feature>
    <feature>javaMail-1.5</feature>
    <feature>cdi-1.2</feature>
    <feature>jcaInboundSecurity-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jsp-2.3</feature>
    <feature>ejbLite-3.2</feature>
    <feature>managedBeans-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jsf-2.2</feature>
    <feature>ejbHome-3.2</feature>
    <feature>jaxws-2.2</feature>
    <feature>jsonp-1.0</feature>
    <feature>el-3.0</feature>
    <feature>jaxrsClient-2.0</feature>
    <feature>concurrent-1.0</feature>
    <feature>appClientSupport-1.0</feature>
    <feature>ejbRemote-3.2</feature>
    <feature>jaxb-2.2</feature>
    <feature>mdb-3.2</feature>
    <feature>jacc-1.5</feature>
    <feature>batch-1.0</feature>
    <feature>ejb-3.2</feature>
    <feature>json-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jaspic-1.1</feature>
    <feature>distributedMap-1.0</feature>
    <feature>websocket-1.1</feature>
    <feature>wasJmsSecurity-1.0</feature>
    <feature>wasJmsClient-2.0</feature>

    <feature>jpaContainer-2.1</feature>
  </featureManager>
```

Thanks to the post http://dplatz.de/blog/2018/wlp-eclipselink-cache-coordination.html.

This solutions works for me, but if anyone has some hints please post it.